# How to configure PHP5.2.11, MYSQL with smarty?

Tags: php, smarty

im new into PHP. how to configure the PHP5.2.11, MYSQL with smarty?

I have installed mysql, PHP separately. How to configure mysql with PHP, PHP with smarty?

Comment: could have been better if you used xampp or wamp to install the server.

Comment: plz tell abt the configuration with xampp & smarty.

Comment: MySQL - PHP : Refer to the docs. Smarty is just an include. It's probably better if you post any problems you run into instead of just a blaknet 'how do I'

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you've got PHP and MySQL running, I'd recommend the "Smarty : Quick Install" tutorial:
http://www.smarty.net/quick_start.php